# Dynamic Div pushing table cells to the left HTML JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, push

I think this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a table with three cells in which, upon click, hidden divs are revealed. However when the div is shown it pushes the cells around it. I'm looking for a way where the div will show but not be restricted to the size of the cell and will not affect the other cells around it.

If there is a better way of organizing this than in a table, please let me know.

Here is some sample code of my problem:

CSS:

```
<style>
    .iphone {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //Choose iPhone model
    function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.model').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).slideDown(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }
     });
    }   

        //Choose iPhone carrier
        function slideonlytwo(thechosentwo) {
         $('.carrier').each(function(index) {
              if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosentwo) {
                   $(this).slideDown(200);
              }
              else {
                   $(this).slideUp(600);
              }
         });
        }   
        </script>
```

HTML:
    
       
          
             
                
                  
**iPhone 5**

```
           <div class="model" id="iphone5" style="display: none;padding: 15px;">
              <table width="80%">
                <center>
                <tr>
                  <td width="33%"><a id="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5a');"><img src="_include/images/icons/att.png"></a>
                    <div class="carrier" id="5a" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="33%"><a id="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5v');"><img src="_include/images/icons/verizon.png"></a>
                    <div class="carrier" id="5v" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="33%"><a id="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5s');"><img src="_include/images/icons/sprint.png"></a>
                    <div class="carrier" id="5s" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="33%"><a id="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5f');"><img src="_include/images/icons/tmobile.png"></a>
                    <div class="carrier" id="5f" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
                  </td>


                </tr>
              </center>
              </table>
           </div>
      </td>

      <td width="33%">
         <div>
            <a id="myHeader" href="javascript:slideonlyone('iphone4s');" ><center><img src="_include/images/products/iphone4s.png">
              <br><b>iPhone 4S</b><center></a></a>
         </div>
         <div class="model" id="iphone4s" style="display: none;padding: 15px;">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="33%">AT&T</td>
                <td width="33%">Verizon</td>
                <td width="33%">Sprint</td>
                <td width="33%">Factory Unlocked</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </div>

      </td>

      <td width="33%">
         <div>
            <a id="myHeader" href="javascript:slideonlyone('iphone4');" ><center><img src="_include/images/products/iphone4.png">
              <br><b>iPhone 4</b><center></a></a>
         </div>
         <div class="model" id="iphone4" href="javascript:slideonlyone('4carrier)" style="display: none;padding: 15px;">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="33%">AT&T</td>
                <td width="33%">Verizon</td>
                <td width="33%">Sprint</td>
                <td width="33%">Factory Unlocked</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting that div within each table cell as absolutely positioned (position: absolute) and each table cell with (position: relative)

This will prevent the div from messing with your table sizing.

On a slightly related note, change your repeating ID's to "class" instead.

```
<td width="33%"><a class="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5a');"><img src="_include/images/icons/att.png"></a>
    <div class="carrier" id="5a" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
</td>
<td width="33%"><a class="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5v');"><img src="_include/images/icons/verizon.png"></a>
    <div class="carrier" id="5v" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
</td>
<td width="33%"><a id="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5s');"><img src="_include/images/icons/sprint.png"></a>
<div class="carrier" class="5s" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
</td>
<td width="33%"><a class="5carrier" href="javascript:slideonlytwo('5f');"><img src="_include/images/icons/tmobile.png"></a>
    <div class="carrier" id="5f" style="display:none;padding:  5px;"> Next Option.</div>
</td>
```

For your CSS, try:

```
.carrier {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100; /*or whatever your cell height or desired height is*/
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd position the div absolute relative to the trigger or whatever element you deem best. The absolute positioning should resolve your positioning problems. You could do this with CSS however I'd opt for jquery for further control. The below is to give you a conceptual idea about positioning.

```
// get the element to position by. could be row another div or the trigger itself
var offset = $('.element').offset();
// however you grab your div element to slide down this is just to give you an idea.
var modelSlider = ('#id');
// set the offset of your slider.
modelSlider.offset({ left: offset.left, top: offset.top });
modelSlider.show() or whatever you want to do here as to effect.
```

The point is I wouldn't necessarily just slide it but rather position as it needs to be. It's rather trivial to grab a parent or some trigger and then position your overlay according to it. Your code there isn't complete. If you can provide/edit the complete page, I'm sure we can whip up an exact example as this should be fairly simple.

You can checkout => http://api.jquery.com/offset/ to get more info on .offset() and .postion();

Answer (score -1):

It is the padding and spacing cause that issue. Set `cellpadding=0` and `cellspacing=0`.

If you still like to keep the space between rows and cells, add a div in the cell, say,
`<div style="width:275px">`, then put the dynamic div inside it, also will fix it.